# How do I set a class member by name in php?

Tags: php

I want to unserialize a string from a couple different formats. The first format is json.

```
$myObj = new myObject();
$unserialized = json_decode($input, true);
foreach ($unserialized as $member_name => $value){
    $myObj[$member_name] = $value; // <= How do I do what this is trying to do?
}
```

Comment: You can convert the whole array to object (albeit of type `stdClass`) without looping, like this: `$myObj = (object)$unserialized;`

Comment: you could learn php, instead of pretending that it is javascript: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Why all the hate for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as this:

```
$myObj->$member_name = $value;
```